# Detail text label in Swift and EXT_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I am making a to-do application. I use core data. In it I have three objects. Saving succeeds in (`SecondViewController`). But when I load the Table View Controller the application immediately crashes. If I remove the `detailTextLabel` the application works fine.

My code of core data:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Note)
class Note: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var mynote: String
    @NSManaged var mydate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var mytime: String
}
```

My code of table view controller

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellNote", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    if var cellContact = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Note {
        cell.textLabel!.text = cellContact.mynote
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = cellContact.mytime
    }

    return cell
```

[A picture of the error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iqdasoy983il852/error.png?dl=0).

Comment: Is cellContact.mytime null? Use optionals! Test your values before assigning and you'll see where the issue is.

Comment: I tried to do it (Optional?), Does not help. It has a file line that shows the time. let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)

Comment: Remove that variable. Try to simply print a string to test. cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Test"

Comment: It works. It display text

Comment: Then what is the problem? Tell me please.

Comment: The problem is with your cellContact.mytime variable not existing. It appears to be an issue with your date conversion to string.

Comment: Saving takes place correctly, as displayed in the console, data sohraniny. When I set the cursor on the variable and pressing alt + mouse displayed a format String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your UITableViewStyle adheres to the detail view type. Use optionals. Test your values before unwrapping.

```
if let time = cellContact.mytime {
    println(time)
    // Place a breakpoint here to see if the time value exists first before assigning to detailTextLabel.text
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = time
}
```

The problem is with your date conversion more than likely. Try this

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
let timeStamp = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
// Set your mytime here and save
```

Comment: Are you positive cellContact.mytime contains a value? Your NSManagedObject does not have this listed as an optional therefore it will crash if it's not found.

Comment: When I run the code above, the console displays    mytime = "4/21/15, 12:57 AM";

Comment: Thank you very much! You helped me a lot! The application work.